# learning OWA operator weights from data (decision fusion - fuzzy sysems)

Tags: python, machine-learning, fuzzy

i am trying to implement Example 1 from this article : Learning weights for weighted OWA operators (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/343740)

it is pretty straight forward and indicates that in order to update weights we need to update lambdas and for updating lambdas there is this formula :

[image]

in article lambdas after 150 iteration are:
l1= -0.61; l2 = -0.29; l3 = -0.05; lq = 1.51

but i get diff result in my code! here is my code:

```
iterations = 150
beta = 0.35

samples = [[0.4, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8, 0.24],
           [0.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.1, 0.16],
           [1.0, 0.0, 0.3, 0.5, 0.15],
           [0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.17],
           [0.6, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.18]]

sensors = {0: {'lambda': 0}, 1: {'lambda': 0}, 2: {'lambda': 0}, 3: {'lambda': 0}}


def calculate_lambda(sample, aggregated_value):
    sample.sort(reverse=True)
    def calculate_sum():
        dk = 0
        for i in range(4):
            dk += math.exp(sensors[i]['lambda'])
        return dk

    lambda_j = calculate_sum()

    def calculate_dkHat():
        dk = 0
        for i in range(4):
            dk += sample[i] * (math.exp(sensors[i]['lambda']) / lambda_j)
        return dk

    for i in range(4):  # calculate lambda for each sensor
        a = math.exp(sensors[i]['lambda']) / lambda_j
        dkHat = calculate_dkHat()
        derivative = a * (sample[i] - dkHat) * (dkHat - aggregated_value)
        sensors[i]['lambda'] = sensors[i]['lambda'] - beta * derivative


# main loop
for iteration in range(150):
    for sample in samples:
        calculate_lambda(sample[:4], sample[4])

print(sensors)
```

What am i missing? Has someone implemented this articles example before?